# How do you set up a WordPress blog with multiple authors to allow something like StackExchange's "community wiki" feature?

Tags: admin, author, editor, user-roles, capabilities

I'm thinking about having a blog with multiple authors. In the [WordPress Roles documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities), authors can publish posts but only edit their own and not posts by other authors, which is what I'm looking for.

I also want to allow certain posts to become open for anybody to edit without upgrading anybody to 'Editor', similar to the community wiki feature here on the StackExchange sites.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your best bet is to create a custom post type for the certain posts you want editable by multiple authors.

When you register your post assign a capability type (#WIKI# in this example) and then add the 'edit_others_#WIKI#s' to the author role.